# Cocoapods: is there a way to do "pod spec create" behind proxy?

Tags: git, proxy, cocoapods

#### The problem

I am trying to create a podspec for one of my projects using "pod spec create ProjectName ProjectGitHubLink". I am behind proxy but installed Cocoapods with the --http-proxy configuration, and also added a git configuration for the proxy (but only as a "local" setting for my project's git repo). Other pod commands like search work well, but this one hangs, and then the following timeout error is generated:

#### Stack

`CocoaPods : 0.32.1
        Ruby : ruby 2.0.0p451 (2014-02-24 revision 45167) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]
    RubyGems : 2.0.14
        Host : Mac OS X 10.9.3 (13D65)
       Xcode : 5.1.1 (5B1008)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib
Repositories : master - https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git @ 13b8929d5792e2ad8a44cbeaf7a8abf4fca06826`

#### Error

`` Errno::ETIMEDOUT - Operation timed out - connect(2)
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `initialize'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `open'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:878:in `block in connect'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/timeout.rb:52:in `timeout'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:877:in `connect'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:862:in `do_start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/net/http.rb:851:in `start'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nap-0.7.0/lib/rest/request.rb:187:in `perform'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nap-0.7.0/lib/rest/request.rb:199:in `perform'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/nap-0.7.0/lib/rest.rb:24:in `get'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.32.1/lib/cocoapods-core/github.rb:118:in `peform_request'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-core-0.32.1/lib/cocoapods-core/github.rb:27:in `repo'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.32.1/lib/cocoapods/command/spec.rb:414:in `github_data_for_template'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.32.1/lib/cocoapods/command/spec.rb:36:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.5.0/lib/claide/command.rb:277:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.32.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:54:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.32.1/bin/pod:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>' ``